# WebBrowser Control - Bypass Download Alert Window Open/Save/Cancel

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with download a file. I am using a `WinForms` and `C#`. I am navigate my `WebBrowser` control into a html address, and then is opened a window to Open/Save/Cancel, that windows is used for download a file. It's a XML file, I'd like to write a path where it should be saved as well. Anyone have any idea how can i make it ?
This is my code: And it open a Window with Open/Save/Cancel options

Does any one have any idea ?

Comment: Can you show your code that you currently have?

Comment: My code is simply, automaticlly log into a web, and then go to another url address, after this the FileDialog is shown - something like this: [link](http://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=0). And I'd like to be automaticly pressed Save, and the file should save into a for example C/example.xml. And when download will complete the application should be closed.

Comment: Is it possible to "take over" the window which show Open/Save/Cancel ?